# Consider the function $f:\Bbb Q\to \Bbb Q$.Prove that $f$ is not monotonic,find it's range...

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions

> Consider the function $f:\Bbb Q\to \Bbb Q $.For every $m\in \Bbb Z,n\in \Bbb N$ with the condition $\gcd(m,n)=1$ we have: $f(\frac mn)=\frac{m}{n+1}$.Now:
>   a)Prove that $f$ is not monotonic(increasing or decreasing)
>   b)Find range of $f$
>   c)Disprove that: $\forall x\in \Bbb Q,f(x)\leq x$

I think we should find counterexamples for part a,but have no idea for parts b,c...

Comment: What is $f(0)$?

Comment: As defined you get $f(0) = 0$.

Comment: It's not  been  mentioned in the source of the question(Iraninan mathematical olympiad,2016)

Comment: For a) and c), it might pay off to see what happens to $f$ at _negative_ rational numbers.

Comment: @UmbertoP.: I doubt that: what do you mean by $\gcd (0, n) = 1$? Or maybe I am not understanding you properly. My opinion is that the problem statement is inexact, and $f$ is not defined in $0$. More clearly: $f(0) = 0$ should be stated separately.

Comment: Obviously 0 is not in the domain of $f$ because $\gcd(0,n)=n$ for all $n$

Comment: The way $f$ is defined is that $f(r) = \frac{m}{n+1}$ whenever $r$ is a rational number written as $\frac mn$ with $\mathrm{gcd}(m,n) = 1$. When $r = 0$ there is exactly one way to do this: $r = \frac 0 1$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For **(a)**, let us try to find $\frac a b \le \frac c d$ such that $\frac a {b+1} > \frac c {d+1}$. Assuming all numbers positive, this is equivalent to $ad - bc \le 0$ and $ad - bc > c - a$. In turn, these inequalities combined imply $a > c$. Let us choose then $a = 3c$. After simplifying by $c$, our inequalities become $3d - b \le 0$ and $3d - b > -2$. Since $3d - b$ is an integer, we have either $3d - b = 0$ or $3d - b = -1$. The version $b = 3d$ is not interesting, so let us choose the other one, $b = 3d + 1$. Finally, let us give convenient values to $c$ and $d$. For simplicity, take $c = 1$. We want $d$ such that $\frac 3 {3d + 1} \le \frac 1 d$ and $\frac 3 {3d + 2} > \frac 1 {d + 1}$. Notice now that these equalities are true for every $d \ge 1$.

To conclude, if $0 < m < m'$ and $\gcd (m, n) = \gcd (m', n) = 1$, then $f(\frac m n) = \frac m {n+1} < \frac {m'} {n+1} = f(\frac {m'} n)$, so $f$ is not decreasing, but for $d \ge 1$ we have $f(\frac 3 {3d + 1}) = \frac 3 {3d + 2} \ge \frac 1 {d + 1} = f(\frac 1 d)$, so $f$ is not increasing. We deduce that $f$ is not monotonic.

---

For **(b)**, let us prove that the range of $f$ is $\Bbb Q$. Take $\frac p q \in \Bbb Q$ with $\gcd (p,q) = 1$ and $q \in \Bbb N \setminus \{0\}$. We might be tempted to say that $\frac p q = f(\frac p {q-1})$, but nobody guarantees that $\gcd (p, q-1) = 1$. Let us fabricate then $m \in \Bbb Z$ and $n \in \Bbb N \setminus \{0\}$ such that $\gcd (m, n) = 1$ and $\frac p q = f( \frac m n) = \frac m {n+1}$. We must have $n = \frac {qm} p - 1$ and, since $p$ and $q$ are coprime, we deduce that $p \mid m$. Putting $m = kp$ we get then that $n = kq -1$. Since $\gcd (kp, kq-1) = \gcd (p, kq-1)$, we want a $k$ such that $\gcd (p, kq-1) = 1$. A little reflection shows that $k=|p|$ is a good choice, allowing us to write that $\frac p q = f(\frac {|p| p} {|p| q - 1})$. (Choosing $|p|$ and not $p$ guarantees that the denominator is positive.)

$0$ is the only number for which the above reasoning does not work, but it is easy to just say that $0 = f(\frac 0 1) = \frac 0 2 = 0$.

We conclude that $f$ is surjective.

---

For **(c)**, if $m \ge 0$ then clearly $f(\frac m n) = \frac m {n+1} < \frac m n$, so we'll have to look at $m < 0$. Indeed, for $m > 0$ we have $f(\frac m n) = \frac m {n+1} > \frac m n$.