# Prove or reject: Given the following function,show that it's monotonic

Tags: algebra-precalculus

> Function $f$ is defined over $\Bbb Q$  so that for every $m \in \Bbb Z , n \in \Bbb N$ with the precondition $\gcd(m,n)=1$ we have: $$f(\frac mn)=\frac{m}{n+1}$$.Is $f$ monotonic??

I was confused when dealing with negative $m$ since for example: $$-\frac 34=\frac{-3}{4}=\frac{3}{-4}$$ which gives different values for $f$!!!

Comment: check that $-3/4=(-3)/4$. You can't do $-3/4=3/(-4)$ because $n \in \Bbb N$.

Comment: You are aware what exactly $n \in \Bbb N$ means?

Comment: @Arnaldo,yes you are right,good point

Comment: @ProfessorVector,yes , $n$ is a positive integer

Comment: This was answered the last time you asked here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2198625/consider-the-function-f-bbb-q-to-bbb-q-prove-that-f-is-not-monotonic-find and you accepted the answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\frac{3}{2}<\frac{5}{3}<\frac{2}{1}$, but $f\left(\frac{3}{2}\right)=f\left(\frac{2}{1}\right)=1$, and $f\left(\frac{5}{3}\right)=\frac{5}{4}$. It's not monotonic.

Comment: Bravo,simple and efficient

Answer (score 3):

**Hint**

$$f\left(\frac{p}{q}\right)- f\left(\frac{m}{n}\right)=\frac{p}{q+1}-\frac{m}{n+1}=\frac{p(n+1)-m(q+1)}{(q+1)(n+1)}$$

we have to check the sign of: $p(n+1)-m(q+1)$.

$$p(n+1)-m(q+1)=qn\left(\frac{p}{q}\cdot\frac{n+1}{n}-\frac{m}{n}\cdot \frac{q+1}{q}\right)=\\
=qn\left(\frac{p}{q}-\frac{m}{n}+\frac{p-m}{qn}\right)=qn\left(\frac{p}{q}-\frac{m}{n}\right)+(p-m)$$

I think it is enough to conclude that $f$ is **NOT** monotonic.

can you finish?

Comment: Now it depends on the relation between $p,m$

Comment: @HamidRezaEbrahimi: I made a update. I think it is clear now.

Comment: @HamidRezaEbrahimi: Is it clear?

Comment: Please finish it yourself